# why is my google OAuth using passport.js not executing the callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-api, passport.js

I am trying to enable SignUp and SignIn access for my website using google + API with passport.js.

```
router.get("/api/v1.0/authentication/register/google",restrict({ unregistered: true }) ,passport.authenticate("google", {scope:["profile", "email"]}));

try{
    router.get("/api/v1.0/google/callback", restrict({ unregistered: true }), passport.authenticate("google", {failureRedirect: "/"}), (req,res)=>{
         console.log("success");
        res.end("signed in");
        // res.end("success")

    
    });}
catch(error){
    console.error(error);
}
```

This is my passport.js file where I have entered my clientID and secret.

```
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
      clientID:     "CLIENT_ID",
    clientSecret: "CLIENT_SECRET",
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1.0/google/callback",
    passReqToCallback   : true
  },
  function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
   //register user here
   if(req.body===null){
       console.log("yes");
       return done(null, false);
   }
   else{
   console.log("the profile is:",profile);
   }
  }

));
```

Each time when I SignIn using the Google OAuth, but it does not execute the callback function after the authentication is done. It shows an error has occurred.

Comment: What is the error? Can you add it to the question?

Comment: Its an error message that is generated when the website fails. I am using an open source software called reeve (https://github.com/peterjoseph/Reeve) so it has an automatically generated error which is shown when the request or function is not completed or executed. It just says   {"status":500,"message":"It looks like something has gone wrong on our system. Don't panic! While our engineers investigate, feel free to contact us and provide the following code for further details. Code: 1he57cfbkklcavtpb"} and i cant debug it cause the error doesnt show up on the console either

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving it anywhere to redirect to inside your try so it will always fail

```
router.get("/api/v1.0/authentication/register/google",restrict({ unregistered: true }) ,passport.authenticate("google", {scope:["profile", "email"]}));
    
    try{
        router.get("/api/v1.0/google/callback", restrict({ unregistered: true }), passport.authenticate("google", {failureRedirect: "/"}), (req,res)=>{
            console.log("success");
            res.end("signed in");
            // res.end("success")
            res.redirect('/');
        
        });}
    catch(error){
        console.error(error);
    }
```

Comment: I did try redirecting but it does not work. It gets stuck in an infinite loop and says data lost.